# Copying only non-relation attributes django/python

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am copying a model object to another, but I want that it doesn’t copy the relations

For example, assume you have a model like this:

```
class Dish(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Then I do:

```
            my_dish = Dish.objects.get(pk=dish.id)
            serializer = Dish_Serializer(my_dish)
            my_new_object = serializer.data
```

I want `my_new_object` to include only those attributes that are not relations, in this case, name and description.

How do I do that without accessing name and description directly?

Comment: Could you share the serializer class code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume in your serializer you don't want to explicitly define which field to serialize. Otherwise you could do the following:

```
class Dish_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Dish
        fields = ['id','name', 'description']
```

You probably can define these fields dynamically:

```
        fields = [f.name for f in Dish._meta.concrete_fields]
```

or

```
        fields = [f.name for f in Dish._meta.fields if not isinstance(f,ForeignKey)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, you want my_new_object in dictionary format and as per condition pk will give you only one object of dish.
So, you can do this instead :

```
my_new_object = Dish.objects.filter(pk=dish.id).values("name", "description")[0]
```

It will give you exact what you want, just declare the fields you need in values as an attribute fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a *field* from your *serializer* using `.fields.pop(field_name)` method like the below example According that I took from [**`Dynamically modifying fields`** <sup>[drf-docs]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dynamically-modifying-fields):

> ```py
> class DynamicFieldsModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
>    """
>    A ModelSerializer that takes an additional `fields` argument that
>    controls which fields should be displayed.
>    """
>
>    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
>        # Don't pass the 'fields' arg up to the superclass
>        fields = kwargs.pop('fields', None)
>
>        # Instantiate the superclass normally
>        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
>
>        if fields is not None:
>            # Drop any fields that are not specified in the `fields` >argument.
>            allowed = set(fields)
>            existing = set(self.fields)
>            for field_name in existing - allowed:
>                self.fields.pop(field_name)
> ```

Also, you can do this in your *view* like the below code snippet:

```py
my_dish = Dish.objects.get(pk=dish.id)
serializer = Dish_Serializer(my_dish)
desired_fields = {'id', 'name', 'description'}
all_fields = set(serializer.fields)
for field in all_fields:
    if field not in desired_fields:
        serializer.fields.pop(field)
my_new_object = serializer.data
```

Comment: With this solution I still need to specify the fields I want to show while querying. I'd like to avoid it, in case in the future I decide to modify the model, the queries will still work properly